# Mysql Access denied for user (Web Server)

Tags: mysql

I got "Access denied for user" error. But I'm checking username and password. It is not localhost.

ERROR SAYS THAT:
`Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'kagangok_me'@'mt-melody-da.guzelhosting.com' (using password: YES)`

I am learning how api works.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can do the following:

1. Double check user account and password. If account/password is wrong you will get error `1145`.
2. If you are working on a local machine you will need a user like this `'kagangok_me'@'localhost'`.
3. If you can connect and run queries using other tools you can check the existence of a user account by using:

   ```sql
   SHOW GRANTS FOR 'kagangok_me'@'mt-melody-da.guzelhosting.com'
   ```

   - If your account is OK you may get a result like

     > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ...
   - Otherwise you will get

     > 1141 - There is no such grant defined for user ...
4. Contact your DB server administrator in case you have one.